# rgdal not available for R version 3.2.2

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying out the examples mentioned in [this link](http://pakillo.github.io/R-GIS-tutorial/) . I have successfully installed all the packages mentioned as the basic packages here. 
When I try to use command `gmap` (given in the example as `mymap <- gmap("France")` i get the following problem:

```
> gmap("France")
Loading required namespace: rgdal
Failed with error:  ‘there is no package called ‘rgdal’’
Error in gmap("France") : rgdal not available
```

Also I am aware that `gmap` command belongs to the package `dismo`. And I have successfully installed this package.

Comment: Did you try to install `rgdal`? (`install.packages("rgdal")`) Can you provide your `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

to install **rgdal** upgrade your R version to at least 3.5.0

https://cran.r-project.org/package=rgdal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and was getting an error `'rgdal' was built under R version 3.1.3.` when I was trying `install.packages("rgdal")`, and `installation of package had non-zero exit status` when trying `install.packages('rgdal', type = "source")`

But it worked just now, try again.

Comment: how did it worked? I still receive the same error message of the OP: `install.packages("rgdal")` : `package ‘rgdal’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)` (same with `type="source"`)

Comment: try updating your R

Comment: I can confirm that updating R! allows to install `rgdal` package. For installation of the latest R! I followed this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this error is an outdated version of the core R package. On Ubuntu, for instance, this happens if the `r-base` package is installed from the universe repository.

The fix is to add the CRAN repository and install R from there:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: I tried this and I get "The following packages have unmet dependencies: r-base-core : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
               Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @AnnaNaden As the message says you have broken packages in you system. [Check this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) for ways to deal with that particular issue.